# adding css and js file in view for application based on play framework

Tags: javascript, css, playframework-2.5

Adding reverse routing in view file is causing error. Following is the snippet:

```
@main(title = "index")  {
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.at("/Content/Site.css")' />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.at("Scripts/bootstrap.js")'></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
}
```

I have added the css and js file in public folder

```
  [error] C:\myproject\app\views\index.scala.html:5: value at is not a member of controllers.ReverseAssets
  [error]     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.at("/Content/Site.css")' />
  [error]                                                                     ^
  [error] C:\myproject\app\views\index1.scala.html:6: value at is not a member of controllers.ReverseAssets
  [error]     <script  type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Assets.at("Scripts/bootstrap.js")'></script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use following syntax for getting rid of error

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/Content/bootstrap.css")'
```